# Proving $\tan^2(x)-\sin^2(x) = \tan^2(x)\sin^2(x)$ (and trig identities in general)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

The problem is $$\tan^2(x)-\sin^2(x) = \tan^2(x)\sin^2(x)$$

I asked a question like this previously, and understood that one once someone helped me, but now I am back to not understanding with this problem. Could someone show me the steps and help me understand?

Also, I know it's a part of memorizing the trig identities and becoming familiar with them, but if anyone has any tips or something that can help me that would be great too.

Comment: Okay, so the expression $\tan^2{x}-\sin^2{x}$ is your starting point. What's the endpoint you're trying to get to?

Comment: tan^2(x)*sin^2(x)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

General hint: convert everything to sines and cosines, and then there are only a couple of identities to mess with. In this case
$$
\tan^2 x - \sin^2 x = \sin^2 x( \frac{1}{\cos^2 x} - 1) 
$$
Multiplying top and bottom  by $\cos^2 x$, you get
$$
\sin^2 x( \frac{1}{\cos^2 x} - 1) \frac{\cos^2 x}{\cos^2 x} = \sin^2 x  \frac{1}{\cos^2 x}(1 - \cos^2 x)= \tan^2 x \sin^2 x.
$$

Answer (score 2):

$x^2-y^2$ is always $(x-y)(x+y)$, no matter how complicated $x$ and $y$ may be.  So use that, then see what happens when you re-write $\tan x$ in terms of $\sin x$ and $\cos x$.  Factor out what you can.  That should get you on the way.

Answer (score 2):

$$\tan^2(x)-\sin^2(x) = \frac{\sin^2(x)}{\cos^2(x)} -\frac{\sin^2(x)\cos^2(x)}{\cos^2(x)} = \frac{\sin^2x(1-\cos^2(x))}{\cos^2(x)} = \frac{\sin^4(x)}{\cos^2(x)}$$

Answer (score 1):

$\tan^2(x)-\sin^2(x) = \tan^2(x)\sin^2(x)
$

Typically,
the only identity that you need is
$s^2+c^2 = 1$,
writing $s$ for $\sin$
and $c$ for $\cos$.

Writing
$t$ for $\tan$,
the difference of the sides is

$\begin{array}\\
t^2-s^2-t^2s^2
&=\dfrac{s^2}{c^2}-s^2-\dfrac{s^2}{c^2}s^2\\
&=\dfrac{s^2-s^2c^2-s^4}{c^2}\\
&=\dfrac{s^2(1-c^2-s^2)}{c^2}\\
&=\dfrac{s^2(1-(c^2+s^2))}{c^2}\\
&=0
\qquad\text{since }c^2+s^2=1\\
\end{array}
$

The only place where
there might be a problem
is when
$c = 0$;
there
$t^2 = \infty$
(abusing notation a little)
and $s^2=1$
so the identity still holds,
in a limitly way.